# Sqlite : ambiguous column name

Tags: sqlite, ambiguous

I'm a newbie and i try to do that on my database

> SELECT id FROM import a INNER JOIN import b ON a.id-1 =b.id AND b.val =0 WHERE a.val=-1

Pb : **ambiguous column name: id**

My table :

```
CREATE TABLE "import" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,
    "id_analyse" integer, 
    "cross" varchar,
    "date" datetime,
    "close" double,
    "low" double,
    "high" double,
    "T" integer DEFAULT (NULL) ,
    "B" INTEGER
 )
```

I can't understand because i read

> When more than one table is used (in a JOIN for example) there may be two columns with the same name.

And i use only one table !

is there somebody who can help me ?

stephane

Comment: You are using two tables, `a` and `b`, both of which have column `id`.

Comment: In your query alias name a and b both for same table 'import', may this cause problem

Answer (score 24):

Just specify which `id` you want to select, e.g

```
SELECT a.id ....
```

Also your table does not seem to have the `val` column you're using later in the query.

Answer (score 6):

You are actually using two tables in your query, not one, although they both get their data from the same underlying physical table.  The tables are called `a` and `b`.  In this particular query it doesn't matter whether you do `SELECT a.id` or `SELECT b.id` because the values are always the same.  But imagine you wrote `ON a.id = b.id + 1` -- in that it *would* make a difference whether you `SELECT`ed the id column from `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a case where the error happened in sqlite for query:

```
select * from A, B where A.col=B.col
```

The problem was that the `col` was present in both the tables A and B.
This was fixed by specifically selecting all columns from table B: `Select B.*...`

Answer (score 1):

You may also get this error from an ambiguity in your `WHERE` clause. So, for example, instead of...

`WHERE _id = 4`

...you may need to put...

`WHERE my_table_name._id = 4`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to declare field alias using `AS` keyword in the query.

```
SELECT import.id AS id, id_analyse, any_other_field FROM import WHERE ...
```

This is especially useful when you use `JOIN` where id field most probably would be ambiguous in different tables. The downside of this approach is that you have to enumerate all the necessary fields in the query but in some cases this might be particularly useful.